# How can I connect latex and excel to postgres?

Tags: excel, postgresql, latex

Is it possible to run a postgres query from excel and get the results in excel?

Is it possible to run a postgres query from latex and get the results in the place of the query?

Answer for latex: I was able to get results for queries in postgres directly in latex with this link http://hgesser.com/software/latexdb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to Postgres from Excel via [ODBC driver](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/). Process is similar to MySQL described in article [article](http://www.enduserguides.com/software/office/mso/eug_mysqlodbc.html). Second generic possibility how to transfer result of some query is export to CSV format file and import in Excel. It is simple and works usually perfect.

```
[pavel@localhost ~]$ psql postgres
psql (9.1.9, server 9.4devel)
WARNING: psql version 9.1, server version 9.4.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \copy (SELECT * FROM pg_database) TO ~/data.csv CSV HEADER
postgres=# \q
[pavel@localhost ~]$ tail ~/data.csv 
datname,datdba,encoding,datcollate,datctype,datistemplate,datallowconn,datconnlimit,datlastsysoid,datfrozenxid,datminmxid,dattablespace,datacl
template1,10,6,en_US.UTF-8,en_US.UTF-8,t,t,-1,12948,1879,1,1663,"{=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}"
template0,10,6,en_US.UTF-8,en_US.UTF-8,t,f,-1,12948,1879,1,1663,"{=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}"
postgres,10,6,en_US.UTF-8,en_US.UTF-8,f,t,-1,12948,1879,1,1663,
```

Same mechanism you can use for latex http://texblog.org/2012/05/30/generate-latex-tables-from-csv-files-excel/